# String characters (marks) are not counted correctlly

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

Characters as (é) or in arabic (دٌ) are counted as one in a string, how do I make it recognise the mark as a character?
It should be like (د) is a character and (ٌ) is another character.
I don't want to use NSString because I'm using (startIndex) which is not supported in NSString as far as I know.

Thank you

Comment: Why would you want to recognize those characters as 2 characters? Swift Strings are built so that you can use characters like these and treat them like 1 character.

Answer (score 4):

I’m by no means sufficiently knowledgeable in this area to be confident there aren’t some gotchas from this approach, but this appears to do what you’re looking for:

```
let s = "éدٌ"

let separated = map(s.unicodeScalars) { Character($0) }

println(" , ".join(separated.map(toString)))

// prints "e , ́ , د , ٌ"
```

Note, if you create a new string from a sequence of those separated characters, it will recompose them:

```
println(String(separated)) // prints
// prints "éدٌ"
```